# How do I remove blank lines from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, newline

Lets say I have a variable that's data contained blank lines how would I remove them without making every thong one long line?

How would I turn this:

```
1

2

3
```

Into this:

```
1
2
3
```

Without turning it into this:

```
123
```

Comment: Maybe `x.replace('\n\n', '\n')`?

Comment: @smarx It worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this by using `replace()` like `data.replace('\n\n', '\n')`

Refer this example for better understanding.!!

```
data = '1\n\n2\n\n3\n\n'
print(data)

data = data.replace('\n\n', '\n')
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
1

2

3


1
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
text = os.linesep.join([s for s in text.splitlines() if s])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
text = text.replace(r"\n{2,}","\n")
```